# JSON string created in Rails replaces whitespace with plus sign (+)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, cookies, whitespace

Rails:

```
object = Object.find_by(params[:id])

object_items = { "1" => { :id => "123456", :name => "Pancakes Yum!" }, "2" => { :id => "789010", :name => "hello 123" }}

cookies[:something] = { "id" => object.id, "title" => object.title, "object_items" => object_items }.to_json
```

Let's say that object.title produces a string "Hello World"

Cookie Content:

```
%7B%22id%22%3A2%2C%22title%22%3A%22Hello+World%22%2C%22object_items%22%3A%7B%221%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22123456%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Pancakes+Yum!%22%7D%2C%222%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22789010%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22hello+123%22%7D%7D%7D
```

**Problem**:

The JSON string being created replaces/escapes whitespace with a plus sign (`+`) instead of `%20` which means that if I were to read the string and grab the value for `object.title` in HTML/JavaScript it will read it as "Hello+World" and not "Hello World" as expected.

All other characters seem to be replaced/escaped properly - is it because the space exists inside a double quote?  I can't figure out why it's producing this string as it is.

Comment: What if you `puts cookies[:something]`? Is there a `+` between Hello and World or is it only present at the client side?

Comment: What URL-encoding parser are you using that doesn't understand that `+` is a space?

Comment: mus is too short: it's being parsed by the browser - presumably it's JS engine - in both FF and Chrome in OSX the content value is the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why you are communicating with the client via cookies. Why not use a controller action and ajax request?

```
class SomethingController
  def show
    object = Object.find_by(params[:id])

    object_items = { "1" => { :id => "123456", :name => "Pancakes Yum!" }, "2" => { :id => "789010", :name => "hello 123" }}

    render :json => { "id" => object.id, "title" => object.title, "object_items" => object_items }
  end
```

Then request it using jQuery or something like this:

```
$.get('/something/1.json', function(results) { alert(results); });
```

What's the point in using Rails if you're not going to use Rails?

Cookies are CGI escaped before being sent to the client. When the client retransmits them Rails unescapes them.

You can test the behaviour like this:

```
rails console c
CGI.escape("something something")
=> "something+something"
CGI.unescape("something+something")
=> "something something"
```

Comment: We need to persist data and can't go with local storage just yet :(

Answer (score 3):

Since the cookie contents are using CGI.escape in the setter, just pre-escape them with URI.escape, then %20 passes through CGI.escape unchanged, and javascript can unescape %20 back to a space.

```
cookies[:snickerdoodle] = URI.escape("String With Spaces")
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like it is using the old version of percent encoding:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem and solved changing the cookie after the assignation with a regex replacement:

```
response.headers['Set-Cookie'].gsub!(/\+/, '%20')
```